# What is the earliest story with a matter duplicator in SF

Tags: history-of

What is the earliest SF story in which a matter duplicator plays a significant or central role. By a "matter duplicator" I mean a **machine or device** which can be used to easily and quickly produce an exact (or nearly exact) duplicate of any physical object. There may be an exception for living beings.

This would not include miracles performed by a God or other divine being, and would not include devices that only reproduce a single item or very narrow class of item.

I am particularly interested in stories where the social or economic effects of a duplicator are mentioned, but this is not a requirement for a valid answer.

Comments have mentioned the replicators in *Star Trek*. I wasn't thinking of those, and they are later by several years than my examples, but I think they would fit the conditions. I don't recall much detail on how they worked, or what limits they had.

Examples that I know of are:

- [*Rogue Moon*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1285) by Algis Budrys
  (1960) A matter transmitter also functions as a duplicator. No attention to social or economic issues, but lots to ethical and philosophical issues, and to issues of identity, a recurring theme of Budrys's.
- [*A for Anything*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?9650) by Damon Knight (1959)  Duplicator leads to a collapse of civilization and the rise of a Neo-fuedalism.
- ["Business as Usual, During Alterations"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55690) by Ralph Williams (1958) Duplicator seems to lead to only minor social readjustments.
- ["Pandora's Millions"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?45625) by George O. Smith (1945) One of the later stories in the "Venus Equilateral" series.
- [*The Duplicated Man*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?12488) by  James Blish and Robert A. W. Lowndes (1953) I am not sure if this involves a true matter duplicator

Comment: This trope predates science fiction.

Comment: @Valorum Oh? Would you be kind enoguh to point out a folklore, mythological, or otherwise pre-sf use of this idea?

Comment: I see someone has votes to close this on the basis that it lacks detail or is unclear. What sort of added detail is wanted here?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draupnir

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornucopia

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feeding_the_multitude

Comment: [Elisha and the Widow's Oil](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Kings%204%3A1-7&version=NKJV)

Comment: There is also _[Tom Swift and his Space Solartron](https://www.tomswift.info/homepage/solartrn.html)_ (1958)

Comment: @Valorum Are any of those SF?

Comment: @Spencer - Given that the trope predates scifi by about three thousand years, it's not a terribly interesting question as to when it was first used in scifi. It's like asking about the first god *in scifi* or the first time someone used a sword *in scifi*

Comment: https://etc.usf.edu/lit2go/72/japanese-fairy-tales/4846/my-lord-bag-of-rice/

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampo

Comment: @Valorum Draupnir  replicates itself, but nothing else. A  Cornucopia producs abundant, perhaps unlimited fruits and food (mostly breads and other grain products, not meat) but nothing else. The miracle of the loaves and fishes reproduces the food, but nothign else. It was also a strictly divine miracle. The Widow's oil is also a strictly divine miracle, and seems to have been limited to oil. A true matter duplicator would reproduce anything at all

Comment: DavidSiegel Is there any evidence *Star Trek* replicators have been used to produce *Star Trek* replicators? I think your question is ill-posed and you are moving the goal post to @Valorum's comments.

Comment: @DavidSiegel - Hence the lack of clarity. You've needed to add another six rules to distinguish devices that you consider not to count.

Comment: @Lexible - There are a whole range of things that replicators can't replicate, including Latinum and Dilithium. They can, however, [replicate other replicators](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Self-replicating_mine)

Comment: @Valorum Unclear if those are the ones that make brightly colored food cubes. :D Nevertheless, my point stands. :D

Comment: I don't agree that any of these examples are the same trope. What makes a matter duplicator interesting is that anyone can use it, not just a god or prophet, and that anything can be reproduced at will, which has huge effects on society. None of the examples listed seem to have those aspects, whether the are SF or proto-SF or not.

Comment: @Valorum My goal posts were, I think, implicit in my original examples. I will admit I did not have Star Trek in mind, but it probably is an example. My post read:  "*By a "matter duplicator" I mean a machine or device which can be used to easily and quickly produce an exact (or nearly exact) duplicate of a physical object. *" I will edit "a"->"any" butr that is not "six rules". I will also exclude divine miracles, but even together that is not "six added rules"

Comment: If you're interested in early stories which deal with the economic effects of matter duplication, a number are mentioned in second paragraph of the article at https://sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/matter_duplication (none of them predate the stories mentioned by @user14111 though)

Comment: @Hypnosifl 
 Thank you that was quite interesting. I note that most of the stories mentioned are already included in the question, or one of the comments or answers.

Comment: In one named story arc of  the German Perry Rhodan pulp series, matter duplication (both for living beings and equipment) powers the war effort of the eponymous "Master of the [Andromeda] Island". Much too late to be an answer (that arc run from 66 to 67), but maybe interesting to the "economic" aspect of your question.

Comment: @Valorum  NO.  The first time someone tried to describe something previously thought to be magical as a result of human-created technology is always an important milestone in SF.

Answer (score 12):

**1939:** ["The 4-Sided Triangle"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?642965), a novelette by [William F. Temple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_F._Temple), first published in [*Amazing Stories*, November 1939](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?56588+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Amazing_Stories_v13n11_1939-11_cape1736).
At first the device is used to make replicas of paintings and other art objects; later, after experiments with animals, it's used to copy a woman the two male inventors are both in love with.

**1930:** ["An Extra Man"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?59099), a short story by [Jackson Gee](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?13727), published in [*Astounding Stories of Super-Science*, October 1930](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?57716+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v04n01_1930-10_cape1736_edit/page/n119/mode/2up) and at [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/29882/29882-h/29882-h.htm#An_Extra_Man).
A man sent through an experimental teleportation device is accidentally duplicated when the signal is picked up by two different receiving stations. In principle this is a duplicator which can make unlimited copies of anything or anyone. In the story the device is suppressed by the authorities, not to be used again.

Answer (score 8):

It goes back to folk tales. A few hundred years old, at least.

An example may be found in the tale "*Why the sea is salty"*  There are many variations of this tale. They involve a magic mill that can produce anything when asked. Anything includes food, clothing, a house and livestock.  It gets set to producing salt  and nobody knows how to turn it off.  The ship carrying it sinks, and the mill continues to pour out salt at the bottom of the sea, making the ocean salty.

[One version here](https://www.longlongtimeago.com/once-upon-a-time/folktales/why-the-sea-is-salt).

A possible precursor to the tale is [The Mill's Song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grottas%C3%B6ngr),  13th Century or earlier. That mill was only used to grind out "wealth" though, so it's production capabilities are limited.

Comment: "What is the earliest **SF story**.  . ."

Comment: Are you saying magic isn't SF?

Comment: I'm saying folk tales aren't SF.

Comment: They are if they contain fantastic elements such as magic, unicorns or talking wolves.

Comment: Science fiction is not defined or characterized by the "elements" it contains. It is a literary genre or movement or marketing category originating early in the 20th century, produced and consumed by a certain community of publishers, writers, and fans. A fiction story published by an SF writer in an SF magazine is ipso facto SF, regardless of whether it contains any monsters or magic rings or impossible inventions.

Comment: Although I don't entirely agree with @user14111's characterization of SF, I disagree much more strongly with your characterization of "magic, unicorns or talking wolves" as having **anything** to do with science fiction.   Unless a story explicitly links such things to human-created technology (e.g. AI-driven mechanical unicorn) they are fantasy, **NOT SF**.